# Why is my output file empty in my GUI Java program?

Tags: java, filewriter

I am making a User Input with GUI. My main goal is to record whatever the user will input and send it to a file 'file.txt' .

But the whenever I open the file, it's empty, even though I already have typed in the textfield. It still returns empty. I am a beginner in Java.

```
package testpath;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Testpath extends JFrame {

    JLabel label;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton button;

     public Testpath(){
         setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         label= new JLabel("Enter First Name");
         add(label);

         tf=new JTextField(10);
         add(tf);

         button=new JButton("Log In");
         add(button);

         event e=new event();
         button.addActionListener(e);
     }

     public class event implements ActionListener{
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             try{
                 String word=tf.getText();
                 FileWriter stream= new FileWriter("C://Users//Keyboard//Desktop//file.txt");
                 BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(stream);
                 out.write(word);
             }catch (Exception ex){}
         }
     }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testpath gui=new Testpath();
        gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(400,250);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex){}` : maybe you should *at least* try to debug and look at any exception message, maybe there is one. Just suppressing exceptions with "catch everything" (also known as Pokemon catch) is not a good practice to help you debug problems.

Comment: Thank you bro..I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You never close your stream, so its contents are never written to disk.

Just call `out.close();` after your `out.write();` .

You can use `out.flush();` if you want the contents written to disk without closing the stream at the same time. (thanks @Ultraviolet)

Comment: Wow!!!Tsskk2..silly me..thank you bro..you really help me a lot.I didn't notice to close the steam. Really thank you.  Thank you

Comment: I really forgot to close the steam.

Comment: or you can use `out.flush()` if you don't want to close it yet.

Comment: Also use `new FileWriter("C:/Users/Keyboard/Desktop/file.txt", true);` to **append** to the old content.

Comment: And BTW how can I add background color?...where can I add the line of code for background color

Comment: @BlackLotus : what you're asking now has nothing to do with the current question. I suggest you ask another one.